# Java: how to anonymously set field for a lambda class

Tags: java, ruby, lambda, webserver

In ruby i can get request and params with following code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'faraday'

class App < Sinatra::Base
end

Thread.new do
  App.get("/") do
    puts "request:#{request} ---- #{File.basename __FILE__}:#{__LINE__}"
    puts "params:#{params} ---- #{File.basename __FILE__}:#{__LINE__}"
  end
  App.run!(port: 23333)
end

http = Faraday.new

loop do
  begin
    http.get("http://localhost:23333")
    break
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
  end
  sleep 1
end

# request:#<Sinatra::Request:0x28045e4> ---- ex.rb:9
# params:{} ---- ex.rb:10
```

i wanna implement a sinatra like framework with java, but i'm confuse with add "request" and "params" fields in a anonymous way, i know spark-java has following usage:

```
get("/", (request, response) -> {
    System.out.println(request + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    return "smth";
});
```

but i wanna implement like following code:

```
package ro.idea.ex;

public class App {
    public interface Lamb {
        void call();
    }

    public void get(String url, Lamb l) {
        // dynamic set
        l.setField("request", "default request");
        l.setField("params", "default params");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().get("/", () -> {
            System.out.println(request + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
        });
    }
}
```

**so my question is:** how to implement "setField"?

Comment: To begin with, `setField` would have to be part of your `Lamb` interface.

Comment: my question is how to implement "setField" content.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira, i have know what you say, i can add setField in Lamb interface, but i think Lambda interface for java has only one method,if  i add sefField in this interface, it will raise "multi xxx"(i forgot) err.